# Travelling salesman Basics

Tags: matlab

I'm tasked with creating a GUI solution using guide to the travelling salesman problem. It's to have a drop down menu allowing the user to select from 10,20,30...100 cities, then a button to generate a map from the cities and the unoptimized route. Another button is to optimize the solution using a simple method. I've built the code that generates the initial map onto a plot, using the drop down menu selection of cities.

My problem is the optimization. Initially, a random matrix with 2 columns and however many cities selected for rows is created, representing x, and y co-ordinates on a map. The method we are to use is split into 2 procedures, procedure 1 takes the start point, entry 1 of the matrix, and 2 other random vectors, then it's meant to take a random city, compute the distance betweeen it and all the other cities in the tour vector (the one that starts at 3 x+y co-ords), then insert itself next to the city with the shortest route. repeat the procedure until all cities are inserted into the matrix in a semi-optimized state. Procedure 2 takes the full tour matrix, and then attempts to look at each city in it and move it to the position with the least travelled distance between the two neighbouring cities.

The problem I'm seeing is that, whilst deleting a row of a matrix is an easy option, inserting and moving rows is something I've never encountered before. Are there any functions that do such a thing in the standard matlab library?

Comment: As your question is about moving rows in matrix I think you will get more attention if you edit your question so that it will be reflected in the title and immediately  at the beginning. The relation to TSP is not important to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the question correctly, you are just looking for basic matrix manipulation.

Suppose you have a matrix `X` and want to insert a row after the second row:

```
X = reshape(1:8,4,[])
myRow = [0 0];
X = [X(1:2,:); myRow; X(3:end,:)]
```

If you want to move a row:

```
1. Assign it to myRow
2. Delete it
3. Insert the new row with the code above
```

If you want to swap rows, you can take a more direct route, suppose you want to swap row 2 and 4:

```
X = reshape(1:8,4,[])
X([2 4],:) = X([4 2],:)
```

If you simply want to update a row, it gets even easier. Suppose you want to update the second row:

```
X = reshape(1:8,4,[])
myRow = [0 0];
X(2,:) = myRow
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answering. I'm pretty terrible at matlab. What's the purpose of the reshape function. If I'm understanding your code correctly, wouldn't the last 2 lines swap rows around?

Comment: @Thallazar The reshape is just to (re)create a sample matrix with values 1:8.  This way you can run each fragment on its own.